# How to delete previous html so, when ngOnChanges is used, not to doublicate the result

Tags: html, angular

I need your help in my project, because I'm new to Angular 2. I have the below problem and I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

I have created a Calendar Component, which has an `@Input() variable ("inputDate")`, which is a Date object. The component creates a table of the input month.

The parent component (app.component) changes the "`inputDate`" through the tag

```
<calendar [inputDate]="date"></calendar>
```

The initial value of "`date`" is the current date and, by pressing a button, the variable changes to a random value (I know there isn't any logic here, just testing).

The main problem is this: When I start the application, the calendar table with the current month appears (I mean the first day of the month is on the right cell, eg Saturday). So far so good. However, when I press the button in order to change the "inputDate" value, it appears a new calendar table below the old one without deleting it. And the strange thing is that the dates (the cell on which the first day of the month begins and the following ones) have changed not only on the new calendar table but also on the old one.

So, how can I have only one calendar table with the right dates each time??

My final goal is to include arrows in my calendar in order to move between previous and next months. Should I put these arrows into the parent component or inside the Calendar Component???

Thanks a lot in advance!!

A part of my project code is given below:

app.component.ts

```
    export class AppComponent  {
       date: Date = new Date();

       showNextMonth() {
          let month = Math.random() * 10;
          this.date = new Date(2020, month);
    }
```

app.component.html

```
    <!-- Main Content Area -->
    <div class="main-content-area">
        <button (click)="showNextMonth()">NEXT MONTH</button>
        <calendar [inputDate]="date"></calendar>
    </div>
```

calendar.component.html

```
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let w of noOfWeeksOfMonth">
            <td *ngFor="let d of days">
                {{ createDaysOnCalendar(w, d, monthLength, firstDayOfMonth) }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

calendar.component.ts

```
    export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
      @Input() inputDate: Date;

      myDate: string;
      firstDayOfMonth: number;
      monthLength: number;

      days_labels = ['ΔΕ', 'ΤΡ', 'ΤΕ', 'ΠΕ', 'ΠΑ', 'ΣΑ', 'ΚΥ'];
      months_labels = ['Ιανουάριος', 'Φεβρουάριος', 'Μαρτιος', 'Απρίλιος',
               'Μάιος', 'Ιούνιος', 'Ιούλιος', 'Αύγουστος',
               'Σεπτέμβριος', 'Οκτώβριος', 'Νοέμβριος', 'Δεκέμβριος'];
      month_length = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
      noOfWeeksOfMonth: number[] = []; // To determine how much rows in the calendar we have to create.
      days = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

      currentMonth: number;
      currentDate: number;
      currentYear: number;
      currentDay: number;

      ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
        this.createCalendar(this.inputDate);
      }

      createCalendar(date: Date) {
        let currentDay_temp = date.getDay();
        let currentDay = (currentDay_temp === 0 ? 6 : currentDay_temp - 1); // getDay() returns 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday etc.
                                                                            // I want 0 for Monday, 1 for Tuesday, etc.
        let currentDate = date.getDate();      // from 1 to 31.
        let currentMonth = date.getMonth();    // 0 for January, 1 for February, etc. 
        let currentYear = date.getFullYear();  // eg. 2017.

        this.firstDayOfMonth = this.getFirstDayOfMonth(currentYear, currentMonth);
        this.monthLength = this.month_length[currentMonth];
        if (currentMonth === 1) { // Compensate for Leap Year
          if ((currentYear % 4 === 0 && currentYear % 100 !== 0) || currentYear % 400 === 0) {
            this.monthLength = 29;
          }
        }
        this.noOfWeeksOfMonth = this.createNoOfWeeksOfMonthArray(this.firstDayOfMonth, this.monthLength);
      }

      getFirstDayOfMonth(y: number, m: number): number {
        // ...
        return firstDayOfMonth;
      }

      createNoOfWeeksOfMonthArray(firstDayOfMonth: number, monthLength: number) {
        // ...
        return this.noOfWeeksOfMonth;
      }

      createDaysOnCalendar(w: number, d: number, monthLength: number, firstDayOfMonth: number) {
        let day_count = ((w - 1) * 7) + d;
        if (day_count < (monthLength + firstDayOfMonth) && day_count >= firstDayOfMonth) {
          return day_count - firstDayOfMonth + 1;
        }
      }
    } // End of Component.
```

Comment: I started a plunker for you here: https://plnkr.co/edit/gafnmQSw9rgV3RB5Z7Rn?p=preview. Please fork and make it so it replicates your issue, then add it to your question so that I/others can debug and help.

Comment: ''  https://plnkr.co/edit/nDr3XYKv0Bx4TgcKP92C?p=preview  ''. Thank you Ahmed! In the above link, I have uploaded my code and my issue is replicated. If anyone know what is going on, please help because I am really stuck!!

Comment: You're welcome, looks like someone beat me to the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is, that you are just pushing values to `NoOfWeeksOfMonth`, so the new data just gets added to this array, you need to empty the array at some point, here I do it inside `create calendar`, before calling `createNoOfWeeksOfMonthArray` function.

```
this.noOfWeeksOfMonth= []; // here
this.noOfWeeksOfMonth = this.createNoOfWeeksOfMonthArray(this.firstDayOfMonth, this.monthLength);
```

As you can see below, inside the function `createNoOfWeeksOfMonthArray` we just push new values here:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= NoOfWeeksOfMonth; i++) {
   this.noOfWeeksOfMonth.push(i);
}
```

So now when we have emptied the array before this, we have fresh empty array to work with :)

Your forked

### [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cpJzhE8OgYHRIQmwIiBQ?p=preview)

Comment: You' re right! I totally overlooked it! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)